# Enviar correo con Genexus SMTP Java

Tags: genexus, smtp

Estoy intentando realizar el envío de correos en GeneXus con SMTP en un entorno desarrollado con java y el código no me muestra ningún error, pero no realiza la acción de enviar el correo

```
&correomio = 'correo@gmail.com'
if &EnvioFecha = &fecha
    &SMTP.Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    &SMTP.Port = 465 
    &SMTP.Sender.Address = 'correo@gmail.com'
    &SMTP.Sender.Name    = 'nombre'
    &SMTP.UserName       = 'correo@gmail.com'
    &SMTP.Password       = 'contraseña'
    &SMTP.ErrDisplay     = 1
    &Valor = &SMTP.ErrCode
    &SMTP.Authentication = 1
    &SMTP.Secure = 1
    &SMTP.Login()
    &Firmado = 1
    If &Firmado = 1
        &CodigoErrorEnvio = 0
        &MensajeErrorEnvio = ''
        &Mail.To.New(&correomio,&correomio)
        &Mail.Subject = 'Recodatorio'
        &mail.HTMLText = 'Recordatorio'
        
        &SMTP.Send(&Mail)
        
        &CodigoErrorEnvio = &SMTP.ErrCode
        &MensajeErrorEnvio = &SMTP.ErrDescription
        &Mail.To.Clear()
        &Mail.Attachments.Clear()
        &Mail.Clear()
    Endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que el problema no lo tengas en el SEND, que es donde estas capturando el log, sino en el Login().

Podrias fijarte eso asi:

```
 &ret = &SMTPSession.Login() 
    if &SMTPSession.ErrCode <> 0 
       &MailMsg = &ret.ToString() + ':Error al loguease'
       Do 'ManageError'                     //subroutine that manages errors  
    else
        ... //codigo que hace el Send()
```

Ademas, creo que deberias darle permisos desde 'Seguridad' de tu cuenta de gmail (la que usas para el envio), para que pueda enviar mails con una clave unica (y usar esa al momento de enviar el email desde gx).

Mas info: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=es-419

Wiki GX: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?50227,Special+considerations+for+SMTPSession+or+Pop3Session+with+Google+Accounts